# How to clear textfield while uncheck the checkbox in vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I wan to clear the textfield when I uncheck the check box.

When I check the checkbox it is showing two textfields one is Partial amount and second one is description.

After uncheck the checkbox also data is showing in the both textfields.

My requirement is after uncheck the checkbox both textfields should not show values.

Here is my code:

isMakingPartialPayment: false

```
<v-flex xs12 md6 v-if="(user.type == 'admin'  || user.type == 'customer' || isAuthUserHasInvoiceAccess) && hasPartialPaymentFeature">
                        <h4>Payment Adjustment</h4>
                        {{isMakingPartialPayment}}
                        <v-flex :class="invoiceInfo.partialAmount ? 'payment-adjustment-style' : ''">
                          <v-checkbox data-testid="invoice-payment-adjustment-checkbox" v-model="isMakingPartialPayment" :label="`I want to pay a portion of this invoice`"></v-checkbox>
                          <v-flex v-if="isMakingPartialPayment">
                            <h4>Amount approved to pay:</h4>
                             <money-text-field :fieldType="'partialAmount'" :invoicedAmount="invoiceInfo.amount" data-testid="invoice-partial-amount" v-model="invoiceInfo.partialAmount" ></money-text-field>
                          </v-flex>
                          <v-flex v-if="isMakingPartialPayment">
                            <h4>Reason for not paying full amount:</h4>
                            <v-text-field data-testid="invoice-payment-adjustment-reason" :rules="partialAmountReasonRules" type="text" light v-model="invoiceInfo.reasonForPartialAmount" solo label="reason (required)"> </v-text-field>
                          </v-flex>
                        </v-flex>
                      </v-flex>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a watcher on your model value.

Using vue3 syntax

```js
const invoiceInfo = reactive(
{
 reasonForPartialAmount:'', 
 partialAmount: '', 
 isMakingPartialPayment: false,
})

watch(() => invoiceInfo.isMakingPartialPayment, value => {
 if (!value) {
   invoiceInfo.reasonForPartialAmount = ''
   invoiceInfo.partialAmount = '' 
 }
})
```